# Insert Interval data using jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, querydsl, jooq-sbt-plugin

I have a PostgreSQL table with column with column name test_interval and type interval.

```
test_interval interval
```

I am using jooq to insert the data in the table. In my TestTable.java class, the field is of type:

```
public final TableField<TestTable, YearToSecond> TEST_INTERVAL = createField(DSL.name("test_interval"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTERVAL.nullable(false), this, "");
```

I am creating the table as:

```
dsl.createTableIfNotExists(TestTable)
   .column(TestTable.TEST_INTERVAL)
   .execute()
```

I want to insert the data into the table and the data is of form:

```
val str = "0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 15 mins 0.00 secs"   
dsl.insertInto(
    TestTable,
    TestTable.TEST_INTERVAL
).values(
    str
)
```

I get error can not insert of type. How can i insert data of the interval data type of postgres using jooq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TEST_INTERVAL` column is of type `YearToSecond`, so you have to insert a value of that type, not of type `String`.

Just call the [`YearToSecond` constructor](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/types/YearToSecond.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.jooq.types.YearToMonth,org.jooq.types.DayToSecond))

```java
new YearToSecond(
  new YearToMonth(),
  new DayToSecond(0, 0, 15)
)
```

Comment: I did YearToSecond.valueOf(str) where str = "0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 15 mins 0.00 secs"  Did not work for me

@LukasEder

Comment: Yes, that's a PostgreSQL specific format which isn't supported by that method. Why not just call the constructor with specific values? See my updated answer.